how to derive the feature importance based on information?
Suppose we have features $x_1,...,x_n$ and target $y$, we want to decide the feature importance of each $x_i$ to $y$. Define a quantity (based on information) like: $I(y,x_1,...,x_n) = log_2(P(y|x_1,...,x_n) / P(y))$, how to derive the equation $I(y,x_1,...,x_n)=I(y,x_1) + I_{x_1}(y,x_2)+...+I_{x_1,...,x_{n-1}}(y,x_n)$? where $I_{x_1}(y,x_2)$ means given knowing $x_1$ what is the information $x_2$ could provide to $y$.
My effort:
$P(y|x_1,...,x_n)=P(y,x_1,...,x_n)/P(x_1,...,x_n)$, and $P(y|x_1,...,x_{n+1})=P(y,x_1,...,x_{n+1})/P(x_1,...,x_{n+1}) = P(y,x_{n+1}|x_1,...,x_n)*P(x_1,...,x_n) / P(x_{n+1} | x_1,...,x_n) / P(x_1,...,x_n) = P(y,x_{n+1}|x_1,...,x_n)/P(x_{n+1} | x_1,...,x_n)$...not sure how to continue...

Clarification requested: "how to derive the equation $I(y,x_1,...,x_n)=I(y,x_1) + I_{x_1}(y,x_2)+...+I_{x_1,...,x_{n-1}}(y,x_n)$?" - What leads you to intuitively suspect that this equation is generally valid?

Thanks! I read it from a paper which is written by Chinese...It seems that we can step-wisely fix one variable at a time, then quantify the information contribution of another to y?

"...I read it from a paper..." : How did the paper either demonstrate the assertion or provide some intuitive insight that would make one suspect that the assertion is true?

this one: equation 2 and 3. DOI:10.1360/972013-665. It is called "the information index model"...but I didn't find it in google.

The question has very little to do with feature importance per se. I suppose the equation you're looking at is used in some way in the paper that you mention, but the formula is generic. Let me write $x_{i}^j = (x_i, x_{i+1}, \cdots, x_j)$. Then $$ \frac{P(y|x_1^n)}{P(y)} = \frac{P(y|x_1^n)}{P(y|x_1^{n-1})} \cdot \frac{P(y|x_1^{n-1})}{P(y)} \\ = \frac{P(y|x_1^n)}{P(y|x_1^{n-1})} \cdot \frac{P(y|x_1^{n-1})}{P(y|x_1^{n-2})} \cdot \frac{P(y|x_1^{n-2})}{P(y)} \\ \vdots \\ = \prod_{i = 1}^n \frac{P(y|x_1^i)}{P(y|x_{1}^{i-1})},$$ where $P(y|x_1^0) := P(y)$. Now take a logarithm on both sides.

Thanks for your answer! I think the approach aims at to quantify the information of $x_i$ by using $P(y|x_1^i)/P(y|x_1^{I-1})$
